# Asp.net RegisterStartupScript not firing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my asp.net application, I am trying to call a `Javascript` function, by doing the following:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "goToDiv", "function goToDiv(){window.location.hash = '#ctl00_body_ApplicationFormContainer'};", true);
```

But it is not firing.

The `JavaScript` function is being called after a postback event, but I think it should still fire, as I added the following code to my `Page_Load`:

```
if (IsPostBack)
    {
        Response.Write("POSTBACK:" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff"));            
    }
```

and changed the startupscript to:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "goToDiv", "alert('POSTBACK: "+DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.ffffff")+"')", true);
```

and the `JavaScript` alert time was after the postback time, telling me the `JavaScript` alert is fired after the postback?

I then changed the code back and went to the sources tab in the console, before the startup script had been run, and entered:

```
goToDiv()
```

which gave the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: goToDiv is not defined(…)
```

eg the function does not exist.

I then entered it again, after the startup script event, and it ran, so I know the function is created - so why is it not running?

My code seems to be syntactically correct, so I cannot see what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:-

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "goToDiv",
   "function goToDiv(){window.location.hash = '#ctl00_body_ApplicationFormContainer'};",
    true);
```

is simply adding a Javascript function but not executing it. You need to trigger this function right?

Simply add a button to test:-

```
<input type="button" onclick="goToDiv()"  value="Foo" />
```

When you click this button it will execute this Javascript function.

If your intention is to execute some piece of block then why you are creating a function? You can execute the Javascript statements itself.

> and the JavaScript alert time was after the postback time, telling me
>   the JavaScript alert is fired after the postback?

Yes obviously, you are registering the Javascript code at server side so when the page is rendered in the browser(client) only then your JS code will be executed.